# How to ensure only one checkbox is selected in the cloud page?

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, cloudpage

I was not sure that you can only select one radio button. Currently both responses are being collected. [image]

Any help appreciated.

```
 <div class="sc-formfield-input"><label>&nbsp;<!-- Just Blank--></label>
   <label class="Checkbox">
   <input type="radio" name="No" data-field-type="Boolean">&nbsp;Will Not Attend 
     <input type="radio" name="Yes" data-field-type="Boolean">&nbsp;Will Attend
   </label>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe how this is related to Salesforce and what functionality you are using.

Comment: @DavidCheng It's [CloudPages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_cloudpages.htm&type=5&language=en_US).

Comment: Yes, it's the cloud pages in the marketing cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "name" must be the same for both input fields; this is what links radio buttons together. Use the "value" to specify the value that should be used.

```
<div class="sc-formfield-input"><label>&nbsp;<!-- Just Blank--></label>
    <input type="radio" id="willNotAttend" name="attendance" value="No" data-field-type="Boolean">
    <label for="willNotAttend">Will Not Attend</label>
    <input type="radio" id="willAttend" name="attendance" value="Yes" data-field-type="Boolean">
    <label for="willAttend">Will Attend</label>
</div>
```

You can read more about this behavior in [`<input type="radio">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio).

Comment: Thanks, sfdcfox. It did fix the problem with radio button but introduce another problem.  Now the responses from both radio buttons are no longer registering in the data extension. I am guessing changing the name to same affected both?

Comment: @calo Unfortunately, I don't know enough about Marketing Cloud to know how to fix that problem. I just knew how to fix the current problem, since that's just basic HTML.

Comment: Thanks, sfdcfox. This was still helpful.